# using one table to update another table in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, merge, apache-spark-sql

I have two table or `dataframes`, and I want to using one to update another one. Also I have know spark sql  does not support `update a set a.1= b.1 from b where a.2 = b.2 and a.update < b.update`.
Please suggest me how can i achieve this as it is not possible in spark.

table1

```
+------+----+------+
|number|name|update|
+------+--- -------+
|     1|   a| 08-01|
|     2|   b| 08-02|
+------+----+------+
```

table2

```
    +------+----+------+
    |number|name|update|
    +------+--- -------+
    |     1|  a2| 08-03|
    |     3|   b| 08-02|
    +------+----+------+
```

I want to get this:

```
    +------+----+------+
    |number|name|update|
    +------+--- -------+
    |     1|  a2| 08-03|
    |     2|   b| 08-02|
    |     3|   b| 08-02|
    +------+----+------+
```

Are there have any other way to do this in spark?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pyspark`, you could use `subtract()` to find the `number` values of `table1` not present in `table2`, and consequently use `unionAll` of the two tables where `table1` is filtered down to the missing observations from `table2`.

```
diff = (table1.select('number')
        .subtract(table2.select('number'))
        .rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect())

table2.unionAll(table1[table1.number.isin(diff)]).orderBy('number').show()
+------+----+------+
|number|name|update|
+------+----+------+
|     1|  a2| 08-03|
|     2|   b| 08-02|
|     3|   b| 08-02|
+------+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks！But I have use spark-shell~~